# how to fire a event for page attribute option in wordpress 5.0?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

After I updated Wordpress to 5.0, I want to fire a JS event for the page template attribute with jQuery, but it doesn't work anymore.

For example, see the screenshot first:

[image]

I write the following jQuery change event for the select component in my plugin:

```
$('#inspector-select-control-0').change(function(){
     alert('Fired!');
});
```

But it doesn't work, what's wrong? Could anyone remind me? Thanks!

Comment: What are the two errors in your console log?

Comment: It seems has nothing to do with my script. VM2491 load-scripts.php:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed. Just leave the solution here.
Simply add all scripts within $(window).load(function(){  .... });